# Change class in all TDs that are children to a given TH?

Tags: jquery, html

Simple question (I think) - I want to add a checkbox to a few table headers (TH) in a given table, and when checked it should add a class to all the TDs in that column, and vice versa - when unchecked it should remove that class from all the TDs in that specific column.

Is this doable with jQuery? I can't figure it out...

Comment: Yep, it's doable! Start with a `change` event - and check the column index.

Comment: _"Is this doable with jQuery?"_ Of course it is. What have you tried? With nearly 12K rep I would expect that you know that your question is poorly written and shows no research effort.

Comment: @j08691 from those 12k, 11.6k is from a question he asked 4 years ago ;)

Comment: I've done research, I just didn't know what exactly to look for... as per coderfin's solution below, index() function in jQuery was something I should've been looking for (never heard of it before), so... downvote and judge all you want, sometimes you just don't know what to look for and ask for to begin with. Don't tell me you've never been there. And I already spent half an hour Googling possible approaches and solutions to this without any help, so figured this would be a better use of my time instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.  Here is one solution.

```js
$("th input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
    var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    
    $("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
table, tr, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.highlight {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </th>
            <th>Column 2
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
            <td>Cell 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 5</td>
            <td>Cell 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's exactly it. I wasn't sure index() even existed or how to use it in this way, so that definitely changes things a bit in terms of jQuery now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#cb1').change(function() {
    var columnTd = $(".needClass > tr > td");

    if($("#cb1").is(":checked")){
        alert("add class")
        columnTd.addClass("newClass");
    }else{
        columnTd.removeClass("newClass");
        alert("remove class")
    }            
});
```

See example in jsfiddler https://jsfiddle.net/d1govvgr/